# Continuously getting TypeError:'NoneType' from appempting to access the .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm attempting to do asimple menu kivy app and I keep getting the `if current_property[:3] == 'on_': TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error. Here is the python file that build's a test Label named Manz to see if I can get it working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Manz(Label):
    pass

class NavAirApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Manz()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NavAirApp().run()
```

and here is my .kv file named navair.kv

```
<Manz>:
    text: 'hi'
```

Comment: What you posted here works fine

Comment: @ George BouThen could it be a problem with the way I have downloaded the kivy directories?

Comment: Could be. Some other possible reasons could be messing up with kivy files. Or naming your python files the same with kivy files...

Comment: @George I just named its main.py. And the problem only seems to be with the kivy language itself. If i use the kivy libraries just in python then my code workds, but a .kv throws it off kilter.

Comment: How have you installed kivy? Which kivy version do you use?

Comment: @syntonym I used the stable build for python 2. I can use the kivy libraries but not the language. I'm wiping my computer now and reinstallling anything to see if that helps

Comment: Do kivy examples work? [In this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891937/kivy-typeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-getitem) the cause of the error was using stuff in the .kv file that does not exist, so maybe you have a typo somewhere (although I can't find one in the code you pasted).